# SQL Activity Query - Combine Publication List to Data Extension

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio, publicationlist

I have a Data Extension that contains a large amount of subscriber information for mails. As well, I have other subscribers that are stored in multiple different Publication Lists. I want to be able to combine the Publication Lists into the Data Extension or vice versa. I'm unsure of the best way to go about this as I'm currently attempting to create and run a SQL Query Activity in Automation Studio to append the Publication Lists data to the master Data Extension.

Hopefully I'm on the right track, I receive an error when running the SQL Query below and selecting Append to my Master Data Extension

> ×
> Error saving the Query field.Update Type must be 'Update' or the target data extension 'Master Subscriber Data Extension - 11052020' cannot appear in the query.

```
// Starts with Master Data Extension and joins each publication list

SELECT s.EmailAddress, 
s.Status, 
s.[Sub Id]
FROM [Master Subscriber Data Extension - 11052020] s
LEFT JOIN [_ListSubscribers] l on (l.EmailAddress = s.EmailAddress)
WHERE ListName = '<Business Management Resources>'
OR ListName = '<Industry News and Updates>'
OR ListName = '<Northwest Farm Credit News>'
```

This is currently where I'm stuck, am I going in the right direction to find a possible solution to what I'm trying to do in the first place? If so, I'm unsure as to why this error is appearing.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve your requirement. I would rather suggest an automation with the below steps:

1.[Data Extract](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_use_a_data_extract_activity.htm&type=5) of the Master Data Extension
2.[File Transfer](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_as_move_a_file_with_the_file_transfer_activity.htm&type=5) to your enhanced SFTP
3.[Import](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_es_create_an_import_activity.htm&type=5) this file to your publication list with 'Add and Update', option.

Comment: I will give this a shot today and report back with my results, thank you!

Comment: At this point I've gotten to creating an Import Activity but when I reach the Import File input right after Activity Info it says "Invalid File Location" "Make sure the directory has not been deleted or renamed." It was showing up just 5 minutes ago but now I'm unsure of what happened The file path is targeting ExactTarget Enhanced FTP

Comment: I'm able to get the files to show up, I've clicked run once on steps 1 and 2, but I'm not seeing the file when selecting an import file from the ExactTarget Enhanced FTP location

Comment: Have you cross checked the file location? The file location in the file transfer activity and in the import file activity should be exactly same. Also the file name should match in both the activities.